# MacBook pro 2017 touch bar model.. Horizontal Lines on screen

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, damage

While logging in initially the screen doesn't show problems but soon as time moves after some minutes horizontal lines start appearing in the bottom of screen of black or multi colored that progresses till the entire area corresponding to the app dock is obfuscated... So when I shut down at this time and reopen it.. Some lines still remain and it increase like earlier and results in same... Only when I shut down for a long time.. The screen becomes normal after logging in.. But still after some minutes same issue is reproduced... Using Screenshot and analyzing the picture shows that the defect is not reproducible in Screenshot and is visible in direct display only.. Please advice

Comment: generally speaking if you take a screenshot of the issue and the issue is not visible in the screenshot that would likely indicate an issue with the screen hardware rather than the video card or software. You may have to take it in to an Apple Store or Mac repair shop for diagnosis

Comment: Same problem: flickering horizontal lines after some time. At first it was after a few hours, now it's after a few minutes. It starts from the bottom bar then ends up covering the whole display with horizontal lines. I'm heavily using Microsoft apps: Teams, Office, Edge, OneDrive.

Answer (score 2):

The LCD is failing, sounds like. You've essentially already proved this by taking a screenshot that does not display the issue you are seeing (the artifacts). This happened on my SO's 2013 MacBook Air. I believe it's a fairly common issue, sorry to say.

Answer (score -1):

NOTE: I am able to write all the details based on my 2 year experience using
    macbook pro 13 inch.

All was ok & suddenly one day i meet **Horizontal lines** in bottom of macbook screen.

**Here is the situation when Horizontal lines came in my case:**

I heavily fire below GITHUB commands in mac terminal while working on of my project. (Note: my project location was desktop in my case)

**git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
git reset --hard origin/**

then i found my macbook got freeze for seconds & start displaying those Horizontal lines.

** Solution Worked for me:**

1. I forced shutdown mac.
2. I pressed shift+control+option + shutdown button for 10 seconds (to force start)
3. My mac started then i click select restart mac option from top mac
          icon
4. Then i press D button for some some time time until i got window for
   diagnosis - follow process from here(How to use Apple Diagnostics on
   your Mac - https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202731)
5. After mac diagnosis complete i found no hardware issues with my mac & i start
   mac again.
6. Since then i found no such issues.
7. Please follow things to avoid any future issues.

**PRECAUTION TO AVOID IT:**
I not put all in order but mostly all are important.

> I turn off keyboard light, turn off auto screen display settings.
>
> Don’t charge mac 100% all time.
>
> Don’t put your macbook on you body. Wisely use on table.
>
> Alway close macbook & uncheck the reopen window option ( when you
>   shutdown mac pop will show this option.)
>
> Don’t use heavy graphics softwares such as Adobe softwares that is out of your mac
>   configuration.
>
> Keep update mac as soon as new version available. - IMP
>
> Always clean mac so it will be save from dust that goes inside &
>   create issues.
>
> Don’t use mac all day take some rest.
>
> Don’t open un secure websites & movie sites that don’t support or
>   requires video splash.
>
> I deleted all utorrent, crome extensions, all heavy software that not
>   use.
>
> Don't put pressure on your mac screen while travel or in Bag.
>
> Don’t use Apple provided widget on Desktop. (it is overlay on screen)
>
> Don’t keep open multiple application if not need.
>
> Don’t download softwares that supports ads (some time you end up downloading something that cause problem in your mac)

**NOTE:**

if you follow above you will also save yourself  from following problems that other macbook pro users also getting nowadays.

1. Youtube video blink issues - one of the issue in macbook pro
2. Battery issues - fast buttery drain
   Security issue - when open un secure sites

   Macbook start up issue - one of the issue in macbook pro

   unwanted keyboard light flickering issue - one of the issue in
   macbook

   Mac freez / hang - one of the issue in macbook

   Audio / Voice issue -  one of the issue in macbook

   not responding issue while trying to interact with applications.
   such as login time, surfing google.

Additionally:
I am not sure but i have following observation:

1.Issues arises in my mac such as video blinking, Mac freezing, battery draining fast, V|Horizontal lines etc ...Only when i had Microsoft/Adobe/Google softwares in my mac. (Try to use Microsoft suite/  Google Drive online versions)